# Yii , hidden dropdown

Tags: yii

i am trying to make a dropdown , but i don't want i to be visible for now , here is the code.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'lang_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model,'lang_id',CHtml::listData(Lang::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'lang_id'); ?>
</div>
```

How do i make this `type = 'hidden'` or something like that ?

In other words , i want to keep the field but i don't want it to be shown.

Comment: well m not getting you..so can you please clear your requirement..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also, you can define style attribute of your dropDownList.

```
public static string dropDownList(string $name, string $select, array $data, array $htmlOptions=array ( ))
```

You can try with:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'lang_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'lang_id',CHtml::listData(Lang::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), array('style' => 'display: none'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'lang_id'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

try this..

```
<div class='row' style='display:none'>
```

Comment: i think this will do for now , i was thinking that somewhere in
$form->dropDownList  there was an option to make it hidden

Comment: is there is no option to hidden dropdown.. there is a option readonly not hidden.. you can handle through css..

Comment: If you want to make it visible again, you must use Javascript / jQuery. If you want that to happen, when you manipulate another form element, you  can use its onchange event

Comment: Of course you can specify the 'display:none;' in the dropdown options:
<?php echo $form->dropdownlist($model,'lang_id',CHtml::listData(Lang::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),array('style'=>'display:none;')); ?>